# Is there a way to know how many people are using my public remote node?

Tags: synchronization, full-node, daemon

I am running a public remote node along with a network crawler (xmr.be) and I would like to know how many people are using my node to sync their wallet.

The only metric that the daemon is giving me is the number of incoming/outgoing connections, without differentiating between wallet connections and P2P connections.

Is there a way to know the number of wallet connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only metric that the daemon is giving me is the number of incoming/outgoing connections, without differentiating between wallet connections and P2P connections.

That's not correct, the daemon does differentiate: those are all P2P connections.

Recent daemons do report the number of RPC connections in the getinfo RPC, in the `rpc_connections_count` field. This includes nodes syncing, but also nodes using the RPC for other business, such as sending a one off transaction.

Comment: I just recompiled from source the latest version of Monero (I was using v0.11.1.0 binaries) and now `rpc_connections_count` does appears in the getinfo RPC. Thanks!